# How can I add some generated code in existing method

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, annotation-processing, kotlin-extension

Synthetic adds clearFindViewCache() in Activity.onDestroy() and Fragment.onDestroyView() methods. How can I add extra code to existing method with my own annotation processor?
If we look to the synthetic's implementation we can see usage of classes like ClassBuilderInterceptorExtension, ClassBuilderFactory, etc. Where can I find docs and examples about this API?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Android Extensions is a compiler plugin, not an annotation processor. The Kotlin compiler plugin API is currently undocumented and unsupported; a supported API is being considered for future versions of Kotlin.